# Tem algum problema em adicionar mais de uma biblioteca CSS num projeto Angular?

Tags: css, angular

Quantas posso adicionar? Existe algum limite recomendado? Isso interfere no desempenho da aplicação?

Comment: Você pode ter quantas bibliotecas quiser, mas se está usando pouco elas, ou elas se sobrepõem, seria melhor remover. Se está se referindo ao processo de renderização, até interfere, mas é extremamente risório, quanto ao tempo de carregamento, sim, e muito, quanto mais e maiores as bibliotecas são, mais tempo irá levar pra carrega-lás e começar a renderizar

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta? Não esqueça de aceitá-la caso  esteja satisfeito com a mesma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Quantas posso adicionar?* Quantas quiser ou precisar.

*Existe algum limite recomendado?* Não. O céu é o limite.

*Isso interfere no desempenho da aplicação?* Não (diretamente).

Em contraponto às respostas diretas... Em qualquer aplicação web um dos parâmetros de sucesso mais importantes é o tempo para o usuário poder iteragir com a página. Neste sentido quanto mais complexo for o site (em termos de CSS e, principalmente, JS), quanto mais arquivos forem adicionados, quanto maiores forem esses arquivos, maior será o tempo de carregamento do site.

[Algumas pesquisas mostram que quase 50% dos usuários esperam que uma página carregue em menos de 2 segundos.](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/performance/more/website-performance-conversion-rates/)

[Para o walmart.com, uma melhoria de 1 segundo no carregamento das páginas representa um aumento de 2% na sua taxa de conversão.](https://blog.radware.com/applicationdelivery/wpo/2014/04/web-page-speed-affect-conversions-infographic)

Portanto, não há limites, mas implicações em tornar a página maior e mais complexa, fazendo o tempo de resposta da sua página aumentar. E esse amento leva à um consequente aumento da frustração dos visitantes.